# Render to CVPixelBuffer produces black image

Tags: ios

I am grabbing CIImage's from CVPixelBufferRef's and then rendering those CIImage's back to CVPixelBufferRef's. The result is a black movie. I have tried several variations of creating the new CVPixelBufferRef but the result is always the same.

```
 CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
 CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
 CVPixelBufferRef pbuff = NULL;
 NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];

 CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                      640,
                                      480,
                                      kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                      (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(options),
                                      &pbuff);
 if (status == kCVReturnSuccess) {
    [temporaryContext render:ciImage
             toCVPixelBuffer:pbuff
                      bounds:ciImage.extent
                  colorSpace:CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()];


 } else {
     NSLog(@"Failed create pbuff");
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that CIImage becomes nil right after creating it in the simulator. I did find that if I run the same code on a device then it works.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use glReadPixels to manually read the pixels into the buffer. You can find more about this here.

[Link with implementation is here](https://kmdarshan.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/renderingx-an-image-on-the-ios-simulator/)